# Segmentation fault when run files generated by protoc

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have generated multiple classes from the protobuf files with the protcompiler. In these classes there is the redefinition of the assignment operator and when I try to make an assagnment the program returns segfault. In particular the error that returns is `0x000000000060be60 in PtrTag (this=0x7f1808001a28) at /usr/include/google/protobuf/metadata_lite.h:136 136     return reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(ptr_) & kPtrTagMask`. This function is a library function and I don't know why returns error. There is some library that I have to link in compilation time in addition to the libprotobuf or some object files?

A sample of class generated by protoc is:

```
class LocalizationEstimate : public ::google::protobuf::Message /* @@protoc_insertion_point(class_definition:apollo.localization.LocalizationEstimate) */ {
 public:
  LocalizationEstimate();
  virtual ~LocalizationEstimate();

  LocalizationEstimate(const LocalizationEstimate& from);

  inline LocalizationEstimate& operator=(const LocalizationEstimate& from) {
    CopyFrom(from);
    return *this;
  }

  inline const ::google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet& unknown_fields() const {
    return _internal_metadata_.unknown_fields();
  }

  inline ::google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet* mutable_unknown_fields() {
    return _internal_metadata_.mutable_unknown_fields();
  }

  static const ::google::protobuf::Descriptor* descriptor();
  static const LocalizationEstimate& default_instance();

  static inline const LocalizationEstimate* internal_default_instance() {
    return reinterpret_cast<const LocalizationEstimate*>(
               &_LocalizationEstimate_default_instance_);
  }
  static PROTOBUF_CONSTEXPR int const kIndexInFileMessages =
    1;

  void Swap(LocalizationEstimate* other);

  // implements Message ----------------------------------------------

  inline LocalizationEstimate* New() const PROTOBUF_FINAL { return New(NULL); }

  LocalizationEstimate* New(::google::protobuf::Arena* arena) const PROTOBUF_FINAL;
  void CopyFrom(const ::google::protobuf::Message& from) PROTOBUF_FINAL;
  void MergeFrom(const ::google::protobuf::Message& from) PROTOBUF_FINAL;
  void CopyFrom(const LocalizationEstimate& from);
  void MergeFrom(const LocalizationEstimate& from);
  void Clear() PROTOBUF_FINAL;
  bool IsInitialized() const PROTOBUF_FINAL;

  size_t ByteSizeLong() const PROTOBUF_FINAL;
  bool MergePartialFromCodedStream(
      ::google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream* input) PROTOBUF_FINAL;
  void SerializeWithCachedSizes(
      ::google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream* output) const PROTOBUF_FINAL;
  ::google::protobuf::uint8* InternalSerializeWithCachedSizesToArray(
      bool deterministic, ::google::protobuf::uint8* target) const PROTOBUF_FINAL;
  int GetCachedSize() const PROTOBUF_FINAL { return _cached_size_; }
  private:
  void SharedCtor();
  void SharedDtor();
  void SetCachedSize(int size) const PROTOBUF_FINAL;
  void InternalSwap(LocalizationEstimate* other);
  private:
  inline ::google::protobuf::Arena* GetArenaNoVirtual() const {
    return NULL;
  }
  inline void* MaybeArenaPtr() const {
    return NULL;
  }
  public:

  ::google::protobuf::Metadata GetMetadata() const PROTOBUF_FINAL;

  // nested types ----------------------------------------------------

  // accessors -------------------------------------------------------

  // repeated .apollo.common.TrajectoryPoint trajectory_point = 5;
  int trajectory_point_size() const;
  void clear_trajectory_point();
  static const int kTrajectoryPointFieldNumber = 5;
  const ::apollo::common::TrajectoryPoint& trajectory_point(int index) const;
  ::apollo::common::TrajectoryPoint* mutable_trajectory_point(int index);
  ::apollo::common::TrajectoryPoint* add_trajectory_point();
  ::google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField< ::apollo::common::TrajectoryPoint >*
      mutable_trajectory_point();
  const ::google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField< ::apollo::common::TrajectoryPoint >&
      trajectory_point() const;

  // optional .apollo.common.Header header = 1;
  bool has_header() const;
  void clear_header();
  static const int kHeaderFieldNumber = 1;
  const ::apollo::common::Header& header() const;
  ::apollo::common::Header* mutable_header();
  ::apollo::common::Header* release_header();
  void set_allocated_header(::apollo::common::Header* header);

  // optional .apollo.localization.Pose pose = 2;
  bool has_pose() const;
  void clear_pose();
  static const int kPoseFieldNumber = 2;
  const ::apollo::localization::Pose& pose() const;
  ::apollo::localization::Pose* mutable_pose();
  ::apollo::localization::Pose* release_pose();
  void set_allocated_pose(::apollo::localization::Pose* pose);

  // optional .apollo.localization.Uncertainty uncertainty = 3;
  bool has_uncertainty() const;
  void clear_uncertainty();
  static const int kUncertaintyFieldNumber = 3;
  const ::apollo::localization::Uncertainty& uncertainty() const;
  ::apollo::localization::Uncertainty* mutable_uncertainty();
  ::apollo::localization::Uncertainty* release_uncertainty();
  void set_allocated_uncertainty(::apollo::localization::Uncertainty* uncertainty);

  // optional .apollo.localization.MsfStatus msf_status = 6;
  bool has_msf_status() const;
  void clear_msf_status();
  static const int kMsfStatusFieldNumber = 6;
  const ::apollo::localization::MsfStatus& msf_status() const;
  ::apollo::localization::MsfStatus* mutable_msf_status();
  ::apollo::localization::MsfStatus* release_msf_status();
  void set_allocated_msf_status(::apollo::localization::MsfStatus* msf_status);

  // optional .apollo.localization.MsfSensorMsgStatus sensor_status = 7;
  bool has_sensor_status() const;
  void clear_sensor_status();
  static const int kSensorStatusFieldNumber = 7;
  const ::apollo::localization::MsfSensorMsgStatus& sensor_status() const;
  ::apollo::localization::MsfSensorMsgStatus* mutable_sensor_status();
  ::apollo::localization::MsfSensorMsgStatus* release_sensor_status();
  void set_allocated_sensor_status(::apollo::localization::MsfSensorMsgStatus* sensor_status);

  // optional double measurement_time = 4;
  bool has_measurement_time() const;
  void clear_measurement_time();
  static const int kMeasurementTimeFieldNumber = 4;
  double measurement_time() const;
  void set_measurement_time(double value);

  // @@protoc_insertion_point(class_scope:apollo.localization.LocalizationEstimate)
 private:
  void set_has_header();
  void clear_has_header();
  void set_has_pose();
  void clear_has_pose();
  void set_has_uncertainty();
  void clear_has_uncertainty();
  void set_has_measurement_time();
  void clear_has_measurement_time();
  void set_has_msf_status();
  void clear_has_msf_status();
  void set_has_sensor_status();
  void clear_has_sensor_status();

  ::google::protobuf::internal::InternalMetadataWithArena _internal_metadata_;
  ::google::protobuf::internal::HasBits<1> _has_bits_;
  mutable int _cached_size_;
  ::google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField< ::apollo::common::TrajectoryPoint > trajectory_point_;
  ::apollo::common::Header* header_;
  ::apollo::localization::Pose* pose_;
  ::apollo::localization::Uncertainty* uncertainty_;
  ::apollo::localization::MsfStatus* msf_status_;
  ::apollo::localization::MsfSensorMsgStatus* sensor_status_;
  double measurement_time_;
  friend struct protobuf_modules_2flocalization_2fproto_2flocalization_2eproto::TableStruct;
};
```

Follow the code of the function called in the redefinition of the assignment operator:

```
void LocalizationEstimate::CopyFrom(const LocalizationEstimate& from) {
// @@protoc_insertion_point(class_specific_copy_from_start:apollo.localization.LocalizationEstimate)
  if (&from == this) return;
  Clear();
  MergeFrom(from);
}

void LocalizationEstimate::MergeFrom(const LocalizationEstimate& from) {
// @@protoc_insertion_point(class_specific_merge_from_start:apollo.localization.LocalizationEstimate)
  GOOGLE_DCHECK_NE(&from, this);
  _internal_metadata_.MergeFrom(from._internal_metadata_);
  ::google::protobuf::uint32 cached_has_bits = 0;
  (void) cached_has_bits;

  trajectory_point_.MergeFrom(from.trajectory_point_);
  cached_has_bits = from._has_bits_[0];
  if (cached_has_bits & 63u) {
    if (cached_has_bits & 0x00000001u) {
      mutable_header()->::apollo::common::Header::MergeFrom(from.header());
    }
    if (cached_has_bits & 0x00000002u) {
      mutable_pose()->::apollo::localization::Pose::MergeFrom(from.pose());
    }
    if (cached_has_bits & 0x00000004u) {
      mutable_uncertainty()->::apollo::localization::Uncertainty::MergeFrom(from.uncertainty());
    }
    if (cached_has_bits & 0x00000008u) {
      mutable_msf_status()->::apollo::localization::MsfStatus::MergeFrom(from.msf_status());
    }
    if (cached_has_bits & 0x00000010u) {
      mutable_sensor_status()->::apollo::localization::MsfSensorMsgStatus::MergeFrom(from.sensor_status());
    }
    if (cached_has_bits & 0x00000020u) {
      measurement_time_ = from.measurement_time_;
    }
    _has_bits_[0] |= cached_has_bits;
  }
}
```

In my main function I made somethinghs like:

```
LocalizationEstimate l = localization;
```

where localization is a shared variable with an other process. But this assignment return segfault.

Comment: Requires code for context or that's just an error message we can only look and nod knowingly.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: post edited with more info